# How do I set a in Discord.py a command without Prefix only with certain word to which bot replies and also bot replies to thaat only in dm with bot

Tags: discord.py

`Discord.py`, how to set a command, without Prefix, only with certain word to which bot replies, and also bot replies to that command while `Dm` with the bot.

Remember about the errors for example, bot object has no attribute `on_message`, etc, errors.

Comment: Could you provide a few examples of the kind of messages the bot would respond to and what that response would be?  It's a little difficult to tell what you're asking.

Comment: I mean that  if any user uses a command for example $hello the bot will dm the user and now i want to make some commands that don't have Prefix for example ``hello``  and bot responds to these types of commands only while in dm with a user not on the server

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to pass to [`command_prefix`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix) that will check for one prefix in servers and another (or none) in private messages:

```
from discord.ext import commands

def command_prefix(bot, message):
    if message.guild is None:
        return ''
    else:
        return '$'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=command_prefix)

@bot.command(name='hello')
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.   But can u give me the code by which the bot sends an message after every n seconds. To activate another bot

Comment: See the examples on the [`discord.ext.tasks` documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html)

Comment: It's in cog what about bot.py or main.py

Comment: I saw Rapptz GitHub background task script but how to activate bot to send message continuously Please send me full code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in a cog.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self,message):
    await message.send("Hello!")
```

or in the main.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.send("Hello!")
```

Please reply back if you have an error with this.

`message.guild` will return None if the message is in dms.