# How can I make my discord bot respond to the correct answer?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a bot, which asks a trivia question in my discord channel. I rewrote it a few times already, but can't get it to work on accepting the answer.
I am probably missing something terrible.

My code :

```
# bot.py
import os
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

token=('*removed*')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='??')
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\thund\OneDrive\Documenten\Python programmeren\Discord - bot')
correct_answer = ''

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hello {member.name}, You have joined a Discord server where the Mr. Questionnaire is active!\n')
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'By default you will get questions which you can answer by preceding your answer by ??')
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'There are different prices you can win, try answering some questions and find out!')

@bot.command()       
async def start(ctx):
    global correct_answer
    explanation = (
            'So you want to play a game? We will ask questions, the first one to answer wins one point\n'
            'I will keep firing questions, untill someone types ??stopplease'
            )
    await ctx.send(explanation)
    r = requests.get (url = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1')
    data = r.json()
    category = data['results'][0]['category']
    difficulty = data['results'][0]['difficulty']
    question = data['results'][0]['question']
    answer = data['results'][0]['correct_answer']
    correct_answer = answer.replace(' ','_')
    await ctx.send('Category: %s\nDifficulty: %s\nQuestion: %s\n'
                    % (category, difficulty, question))

@bot.command()
async def correct(ctx):
    global correct_answer
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)       
    await update_data(users, ctx.author)
    await add_experience(users, ctx.author, 10)
    await level_up(users, ctx.author, ctx.channel)
    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(users, f)
    await ctx.send('{} has guessed correctly!'.format(ctx.author))
    bot.command('start')

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await ctx.send(channel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end

@bot.command(name='supersecret')
async def answer(ctx):
    global correct_answer
    await ctx.send('The Answer is: %s' % (correct_answer))

@bot.command(name='%s' % (correct_answer))
async def correct22(ctx):
        global correct_answer
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)       
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 10)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        await ctx.send('{message.author} has guessed correctly!')

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]['experience'] = 0
        users[user.id]['level'] = 1

async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[user.id]['experience'] += exp

async def level_up(users, user, channel):
    experience = users[user.id]['experience']
    lvl_start = users[user.id]['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await bot.send_message(channel, '{} has leveled up to level {}'.format(user.mention, lvl_end))
        users[user.id]['level'] = lvl_end

@bot.command(name='stopplease', help='Stop it right now!')
async def stop_quiz(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Thank you for playing our game!\n'
                   'If you like it, please consider a donation and/or using it on all the servers you know!')

@bot.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    with open('err.log', 'a') as f:
        if event == 'on_message':
            f.write(f'Unhandled message: {args[0]}\n')
        elif event == 'command':
            f.write(f'Unhandled command: {args[0]}\n')
        else:
            raise
bot.run(token)
```

I tried adding a few commands on which I hoped it could fire, but I am missing something completely.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a misunderstanding of decorators. They're quite a complex topic so here's a [basic resource](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/). For you the most important thing is the following: Decorators only run *once* meaning whatever stands in it as soon as you run the file is the only thing it will listen to. 
Now what you are trying to do in your code

```py
@bot.command(name='%s' % (correct_answer))
```

is to have a dynamic value in the decorator, so the bot responds to the correct answer. This does not work! Decorators only run once.

**So how do we fix this?**
We need to rewrite your correct22 function a bit. Your bot can deal with dynamic input via **arguments**. Luckily these are very easy to do in the bot extension.
To even have arguments, we still need a command name, so let's choose "answer". So when before you tried to answer with `??2005` you now answer with `??answer 2005`. You could try to do it like you originally intended but it would quite overcomplicate your code in my opinion because you have to deal with message handlers.

Potential solution:

```py
@bot.command(name='answer')
async def correct22(ctx, answer):
        global correct_answer
        if correct_answer != answer:
            return
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)       
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 10)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
        await ctx.send('{message.author} has guessed correctly!')
```

I have not tested the user features like experience, but atleast the message answering should work like this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I have implemented it, and it works flawless. I am now tuning the experience command as this doesn't add up ATM. I will read the link you have given, that looks interesting. Being curious, could you give me some hints regarding the message handling?

Comment: Considering you're using the bot extension of discord.py, just look at its official documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html. It's very easy to understand. If you're having problems with anything you can add me on Discord (username and tag on my profile).

Comment: what if i want the reply to be with out any prefix like i must just type 2005

Comment: @saiprabhav This is probably what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956326/how-do-i-set-a-in-discord-py-a-command-without-prefix-only-with-certain-word-to
Additionally I urge you to open a seperate question for an issue like this as it has nothing to do with the original question or the comments.